# Polymorphic pointer to parent class not working

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, fortran2008

Consider the following class structure, which involves three separate modules:

!----------------------- in file a.f

```
  module parent_body_mod
  type :: face
     class(parent_body), pointer :: bPtr
  end type
  type, abstract :: parent_body
     integer i
     type(face) :: f
  end type
  end module parent_body_mod
```

!------------------------ in file b.f

```
  module body_mod
  use parent_body_mod

  type, extends(parent_body) :: body
  end type

  interface body
     procedure :: new_body
  end interface

  contains

  function new_body() result(b) 
  type(body), target :: b
  b%i = 123
  b%f%bPtr => b
  end function
  end module body_mod
```

!--------------------------- in file c.f

```
  module body_group_mod
  use body_mod
  type :: body_group
     type(body), allocatable :: b
  end type
  interface body_group
     procedure :: new_body_group
  end interface
  contains 
  function new_body_group() result(bg)
  type(body_group) :: bg

  allocate(bg%b)
  bg%b = body()

  end function
  end module body_group_mod
```

!------------------- The main program

```
  use body_group_mod

  type(body_group) :: my_bg

  my_bg = body_group()      

  print *, my_bg%b%f%bPtr%i

  end
```

!--------------------------------------

The expected output is 123, whereas **the actual output is something random**. The code is compiled using ifort version 18.0.1. Note that the same issue doesn't happen when using "body" class itself, i.e. the following works just fine:

```
type(body), allocatable :: my_b

allocate(my_b)

my_b = body()

print *, my_b%f%bPtr%i ! This produces 123 as expected.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that the function result of `new_body` has an infinite lifetime?

Comment: Yes, I do. As long as the object created by it remains within the scope.

Comment: The function result doesn't exist beyond the function.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am following. Are you saying 'bg%b = body()' assignment is only valid within the scope new_body function and bg%b points to an arbitrary location in memory after the return statement?

Comment: With the caveat that I haven't had a proper look through this.  I could easily be missing something.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is: by calling body_group(), an instance of it is created at some location in memory and bPtr will point to a part of that newly allocated space. However, when the result is assigned to my_b, the previous instance is deallocated, making bPtr invalid. Here, the compiler doesn't realize that bPtr of body_group() is still within the scope. Maybe this should be fixed as a compiler bug.

Comment: If new_xx() is used only as a "constructor" (rather than in a composite expression), how about changing it to a subroutine and pass an allocatable object as an argument (like call new_foo( obj ) rather than obj = new_foo())? Then I guess there will be no problem of dangling pointers.

Comment: You're right, roygvib. That'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is non conforming.

Pointers associated with unsaved local variables of a procedure become undefined when the execution of the procedure completes (F2008 16.5.2.5 (5)).  The function result `b` in function `new_body` is considered such a local variable (F2008 1.3.154.1), hence the pointer component `b%f%bPtr` becomes undefined after the function call.

Function results are a little special compare to other local unsaved variables, in that their value is available longer than the variable exists - see F2008 Note 12.41 for some discussion.

Another way of thinking of the problems is that with the statement `bg%b = body()`, the body on the left hand side is a different object from the body on the right hand side.  The assignment just copies the value of the right hand side object - once that assignment is complete, the right hand side object ceases to exist.  Nowhere is there code to say that when the value of a body object is transferred - the pointer component needs to be updated to reference the left hand side variable being assigned to.  Also note that the left hand side `bg%b` does not have the TARGET attribute - so there is no way that a pointer can be validly associated with it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the complete response IanH (this is actually the second time you're answering one of my questions.) So how would you change the code such that "face" knows to which body it belongs to? I suppose an ugly way would be to assign the pointer after "bg%b" is created (inside new_body_group). The risk is that a user of body_mod might forget to do that after creating an instance. An alternative is to write a function that returns the body provided the face. The downside is that finding the right body can be expensive (as is the case in my application and not really an option).

Comment: You may be able to implement something using defined assignment and finalizers, perhaps with the help of intermediate reference types. Before that you need to be able to describe in words how you expect the objects to behave when their value is copied via assignment and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What roygvib proposed works.